# Powershell Editing Strings in Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

My array has a lot of properties but I'm only looking to edit one. The goal is to remove domains from the hostname but I haven't been able to get it working. This data is being returned from a REST API and there are thousands of assets that contain the same type of data (JSON content). The end goal is to compare assets pulled from the API and compare it to assets in a CSV file. The issue is that the domain may appear on one list and not the other so I'm trying to strip the domains off for comparison. I didn't want to iterate through both files and the comparison has to go from the CSV file to the API data hence the need to get rid of the domain altogether.

There are other properties in the array that I will need to pull from later. This is just an example of one of the arrays with a few properties:

```
$array = @{"description"="data"; "name"="host1.domain1.com"; "model"="data"; "ip"="10.0.0.1"; "make"="Microsoft"}
         @{"description"="data"; "name"="host2.domain2.com"; "model"="data"; "ip"="10.0.0.2"; "make"="Different"}
         @{"description"="data"; "name"="10.0.0.5"; "model"="data"; "ip"="10.0.0.5"; "make"="Different"}
```

The plan was to match the domain and then strip using the period.

```
$domainList = @(".domain1.com", ".domain2.com")
$domains = $domainList.ForEach{[Regex]::Escape($_)} -join '|'

$array = $array | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.name -match $domains) {
        $_.name = $_.name -replace $domains }
    $_.name    
}
```

Comment: `name` is not a native property of an array, and assigning to an enumerated property doesn't work (which might explain the issue you're facing). Can you show us how/where you populate `$array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays use pointers so I needed to load the array and pipe through ForEach-Object and then set the object when logic was complete. Thanks for all of the help.

```
$domainList = @(".domain1.com", ".domain2.com")
$domains = $domainList.ForEach{[Regex]::Escape($_)} -join '|'

$array = $array | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.name -match $domains) {
        $_.name = $_.name -replace $domains }
    $_.name    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do the following to output a new array of values without the domain names:

```
# starting array
$array = @("hosta.domain1.com", "hostb.domain2.com", "host3", "10.0.0.1")
# domains to remove
$domains = @('.domain1.com','.domain2.com')
# create regex expression with alternations: item1|item2|item3 etc.
# regex must escape literal . since dot has special meaning in regex
$regex = $domains.foreach{[regex]::Escape($_)} -join '|'

# replace domain strings and output everything else
$newArray = $array -replace $regex
```